# Replacement for getDescribeInstancesIterator in the new PHP AWS SDK (^3)?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

In the previous version of AWS SDK there were many handy functions like `getDescribeInstancesIterator` which would return an array iterator for results (in this case an array of instances matching the filters).

This function (and similar) have been **removed** in the new AWS SDK. After some research I can find instead is a `getIterator($name, array $args = [])` function defined as an `AwsClientTrait`.

I'm unsure how I can use this new `getIterator` function to replace the `getDescribeInstancesIterator` function, i.e. to get an Array iterator for `describeInstances` function that returns list of matching instances like before (without having to worry about pagination, etc)?

**Any code sample would be extremely useful.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The new syntax is like this

```
$ec2Client->getIterator('FunctionName', 'Values')
```

So `getDescribeInstancesIterator` now becomes:

```
$ec2Client->getIterator('DescribeInstances', [...'Filters'])
```

This syntax is same for all operations including iterating over files in buckets, getting running instances, etc.